# Error Handling issues

Tags: actionscript-3

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation:
```

I don't get this error on my local host but I do when I upload it to my server.  How
do I properly fix this in Flash CS4?

Answer (score 1):

Check where you are pointing to for any external assets or data.  More than likely you need a crossdomain.xml file that will say that it is okay for your server to access the data.  To be clear, you need the crossdomain file where the assets are that you are pulling.

More information here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

An example of a wide open crossdomain.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can specify a domain where the * is and list multiple allow-access-from nodes.  You can also specify all subdomains on a domain by saying *.mydomain.com

To be clear, you do not want to go to production with the wide open example I have given, but it is something you can use to test out and make sure this is your problem.  Once you verify this then you can restrict it to the appropriate levels.

Basically though you just create a file called crossdomain.xml and put this xml in it.
*Make sure it is placed at the root of the server that the data or assets are being pulled from.*